# cma_alloc fails to create memory chunk of 10M

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, driver

I am working on Camera Driver and whenever I try to allocate the memory around `10M`, it fails but `4-5M` memory is created. Is there a limit to memory allocation using `cma_alloc`? If yes, how do I increase it?

Comment: What kernel version are you using? Is `cma_alloc()` function provided by a third-party vendor? It doesn't exist in the generic kernel.

Comment: I am working on Android 4.0 and the its kernel has cma framework.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I'd say allocating 10M of continuous memory is already very suspicious. Why do you need that much?

You're on Android, so that indicates an embedded platform, making 10M of memory even more suspicious.

From the documentation I've found on-line you also need to specify how much cma memory the system needs at boot time. Did you specify more than 10M?

Comment: As I mentioned that the application is camera app. One click takes a frame of around 6-7MB. This requires a big chunk of memory. Yes I was allocating 12M memory. When I increased the value to 30M in defconfig file, it started working. Not sure about the reason how it worked but 12M is still greater than what I required(10M).